# 'xlCategory' and 'xlValue' is not defined in xlwings Charts API implementation

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

I'm trying to do a Charts API implementation in xlwings - python, for basic chart manipulation like adding axis title, changing the line colors, plot marker size etc.

I get an error:

> name 'xlCategory' is not defined

The code for implementation is

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book(r'Tau.xlsm') 
sht = wb.sheets.add(name ='Plot')
tau_plot = sht.charts.add()
tau_plot.chart_type='xy_scatter'
tau_plot.set_source_data(sht.range('E1:F135'))
tau_plot.api[1].Axes(xlCategory).HasTitle = True
```

Can you please help me with this error.

Comment: `xlCategory` is an [enum value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlaxistype) that is defined in the Excel object model. You might want to be using its underlying value (`1`) instead.

Comment: Thank you. This works! You might want to put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xlCategory` is defined under [XlAxisType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlaxistype), an enum that defines a number of constant values. If you're not referencing the Excel  type library / object model, `xlCategory` means nothing to Python/xlwings. Use its underlying value instead (`1`), or define your own copy so that the identifier `xlCategory` is associated with the value `1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Excel's constants as follows:

```
>>> from xlwings.constants import AxisType
>>> AxisType.xlCategory
```